# Refreshing or Rude: addressing an older woman as 小姐

Tags: word-choice, taiwan

太太，奶奶，大姐，阿姨，女士，and many other variations are commonly used to address older women. 小姐 is used to address young women. Would it be a complement or an insult to address a middle aged or elderly woman as "小姐"? I'm in Taiwan here, so we don't have to worry about people thinking we're calling them prostitutes.

Comment: same question may be asked about addressing a 老先生（老头儿、老头子）as 小伙子，or a 小伙子 as 小朋友.

Comment: At my level of ability, which is not very high, I would avoid both complimenting and insulting women I do not know.  I would stick with the common forms of address.

Comment: 大姐 would do the trick because you really shouldn't be calling them *姐* shouldn't begin with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use 女士 with her family name is always safest. e.g. 李女士

Answer (score 2):

In china（中国）， don't ever use 小姐 to address them (sales girl, waiters, etc.).They will totally ignore you.

```
Example :  'when you want to purchase something and ask for help from the shop assistance' - 对不起小姐,请问这多少钱？  
          -'even though we know that in English it is a polite sentence to call someone' - Sorry Miss, may i know how much does it cost?
```

Because for them(china ppl) 小姐 is represented as a `Bar Girl`. Therefore, you have to call them as '服务员' .

In other country, yes. You can address young women or middle aged woman by calling 小姐， for older ladies 大婶 / 阿姨，oldest ladies 奶奶. That would be more cordial

Answer (score 0):

You can adress them as 小姐 and 小伙子 only if you are much more older than them. 
You can just call them as 老大娘 and 老爷子, this is a better way of saluting to unknown elders.

Answer (score 0):

you can call middle age women 阿姨, old ladies 大娘，really old ladies 奶奶，
and call middle age men 叔叔，old men 大爷，really old men 爷爷.

www.ycchangzhou.com